# mysql java no suitable driver

Tags: java, mysql

[image]In the following code..I am getting no suitable driver..error:
please help.  I have been working with it for an hour already and cant seem to figure it out.

It is crazy.  I was able to do this exact feet earlier, before I started messing with GWT.

```
package com.gwt.churchweb.churchweblogin.client;

import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Composite;

import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.VerticalPanel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Label;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.FlexTable;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.TextBox;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HasHorizontalAlignment;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.CheckBox;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Button;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickHandler;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickEvent;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.Window;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Login extends Composite {

    public Login() {

        VerticalPanel verticalPanel = new VerticalPanel();
        initWidget(verticalPanel);
        verticalPanel.setSize("329px", "186px");

        Label lblNewLabel = new Label("Sign into your account");
        lblNewLabel.setStyleName("gwt-Login-SigninLabel");
        verticalPanel.add(lblNewLabel);

        FlexTable flexTable = new FlexTable();
        verticalPanel.add(flexTable);
        flexTable.setWidth("308px");

        Label lblNewLabel_1 = new Label("Username:");
        lblNewLabel_1.setStyleName("gwt-Label-Login");
        flexTable.setWidget(0, 0, lblNewLabel_1);
        lblNewLabel_1.setWidth("72px");

        final TextBox textboxUsername = new TextBox();
        textboxUsername.setStyleName("gwt-LoginTextBox");
        flexTable.setWidget(0, 1, textboxUsername);
        textboxUsername.setWidth("204px");

        Label lblNewLabel_2 = new Label("Password:");
        lblNewLabel_2.setStyleName("gwt-Label-Login");
        flexTable.setWidget(1, 0, lblNewLabel_2);
        lblNewLabel_2.setWidth("66px");

        final TextBox textBoxPassword = new TextBox();
        textBoxPassword.setStyleName("gwt-LoginTextBox");
        flexTable.setWidget(1, 1, textBoxPassword);
        textBoxPassword.setWidth("204px");
        flexTable.getCellFormatter().setHorizontalAlignment(0, 0, HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_LEFT);
        flexTable.getCellFormatter().setHorizontalAlignment(1, 0, HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_LEFT);

        CheckBox chckbxRememberMeOn = new CheckBox("Remember me on this computer");
        chckbxRememberMeOn.setStyleName("gwt-Checkbox-Login");
        flexTable.setWidget(2, 1, chckbxRememberMeOn);

        Button btnSignIn = new Button("Sign In");
        btnSignIn.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                Connection con = null;
                Statement st = null;
                ResultSet rs = null;

                String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/churchweb";
                String user = "root";
                String password = "*****";

                try {
                    con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
                    st = con.createStatement();
                    rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT VERSION()");
Window.alert("Fixing to try it");
                    if (rs.next()) {
                        Window.alert(rs.getString(1));
                    }

                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    Logger lgr = Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName());
                    lgr.log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage(), ex);

                } finally {
                    try {
                        if (rs != null) {
                            rs.close();
                        }
                        if (st != null) {
                            st.close();
                        }
                        if (con != null) {
                            con.close();
                        }

                    } catch (SQLException ex) {
                        Logger lgr = Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName());
                        lgr.log(Level.WARNING, ex.getMessage(), ex);
                    }
                }





                if (textboxUsername.getText().length() == 0
                        || textBoxPassword.getText().length() == 0) {
                        Window.alert("Username or password is empty."); 
                    }
            }
        });

        btnSignIn.setStyleName("gwt-Login-SigninButton");
        flexTable.setWidget(3, 1, btnSignIn);

    }


}
```

Comment: I believe two answers have already been provided to solve this issue. Where are you loading the driver? I don't see this in your code posting. This has to be done in your code for the jvm to load the "suitable" driver. Just having the .jar will not solve your problem.

Comment: String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/churchweb"; String user = "root";  <== doesnt this load the driver, Freddy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the MySQL [Connector/J](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) driver jar file is in your classpath.

Comment: Download the file from the link. Extract it and you will find a .jar file inside the lib folder. Copy this file into the lib/ folder of your project.

Comment: oh i did that...one second ill post a screenshot if i allows

Answer (score 2):

You haven't yet load the Driver to your application,try to add Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

Answer (score 1):

You need to load the driver. There are a few examples in the doc that comes with the connector-j driver from sun's webpage. The following is a snippet of that document.

```
 try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
  } catch (Exception ex) {
     // handle the error
  }
```

If you want to know more about loading the java jdbc driver look at chapter 6 of the connector-j.pdf that was bundled with your driver download.